# Extra window visible when changing PySide.QtGui.QTabWidget UI

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I am seeing an extra window when I change the ui in a PySide.QtGui.QMainWindow. In the example below, I have two PySide.QtGui.QTabWidget I am switching between.

I have tried deleting the existing ui objects with deleteLater() and del.  I have also tried reusing the same QTabWidget instead of constructing a new one when switching UI.

All have the same result as illustrated in the gif below (same result on windows):

[image: Example gif]

I suspect my I am going about this in the wrong way. Any suggestions on the proper way to accomplish this is appreciated.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # instance vars
        self.mode_menu = None
        self.mode_1_action = None
        self.mode_2_action = None
        self.mode_1_tabs_widget = None
        self.mode_1_layout = None
        self.mode_1_content_widget = None
        self.mode_2_tabs_widget = None
        self.mode_2_layout = None
        self.mode_2_content_widget = None

        # Setup the window
        self.resize(750, 550)
        self.create_actions()
        self.create_menus()
        self.mode_1_ui()

    def mode_1_ui(self):
        # create tab widget
        self.mode_1_tabs_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        self.mode_1_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(), "Tab 1")
        self.mode_1_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(), "Tab 2")
        self.mode_1_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(), "Tab 3")
        self.mode_1_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(), "Tab 4")

        # create the layout area for tab widget
        self.mode_1_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mode_1_layout.addWidget(self.mode_1_tabs_widget)

        # create content area widget for padding
        self.mode_1_content_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.mode_1_content_widget.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 0)
        self.mode_1_content_widget.setLayout(self.mode_1_layout)

        # set the central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mode_1_content_widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Mode 1")

    def mode_2_ui(self):
        # create tab widget
        self.mode_2_tabs_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        self.mode_2_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(), "Tab 1")
        self.mode_2_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(), "Tab 2")
        self.mode_2_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(), "Tab 3")
        self.mode_2_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(), "Tab 4")
        self.mode_2_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(), "Tab 5")
        self.mode_2_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(), "Tab 6")
        self.mode_2_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(), "Tab 7")
        self.mode_2_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(), "Tab 8")

        # create the layout area for tab widget
        self.mode_2_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mode_2_layout.addWidget(self.mode_2_tabs_widget)

        # create content area widget for padding
        self.mode_2_content_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.mode_2_content_widget.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 0)
        self.mode_2_content_widget.setLayout(self.mode_2_layout)

        # set the central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mode_2_content_widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Mode 2")

    # setup the menus
    def create_menus(self):
        # file menu
        self.mode_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Mode")
        self.mode_menu.addAction(self.mode_1_action)
        self.mode_menu.addAction(self.mode_2_action)

    # setup the menu items
    def create_actions(self):
        # file menu actions
        self.mode_1_action = QtGui.QAction("Mode 1", self, shortcut="Ctrl+1", statusTip="Mode 1", triggered=self.mode_1)
        self.mode_2_action = QtGui.QAction("Mode 2", self, shortcut="Ctrl+2", statusTip="Mode 2", triggered=self.mode_2)

    # setup the menu functions
    def mode_1(self):
        print "mode 1"
        self.mode_1_ui()

    def mode_2(self):
        print "mode 2"
        self.mode_2_ui()


class SampleTab(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SampleTab, self).__init__(parent)
        label = QtGui.QLabel('Sample tab', self)
        label.move(15, 10)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is due to the following reason:

When you create `SampleTab`, you do not pass any `parent` widget to `SampleTab`. When you create object of `SampleTab`, it is created with no parent at all. Thus an independent window is created for a small interval of time. Means that, as long as the `SampleTab` is not added to `QTabWidget`, it remains independent for small period.

Try doing the following:

```
self.mode_1_tabs_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
self.mode_1_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(self.mode_1_tabs_widget), "Tab 1")
self.mode_1_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(self.mode_1_tabs_widget), "Tab 2")
self.mode_1_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(self.mode_1_tabs_widget), "Tab 3")
self.mode_1_tabs_widget.addTab(SampleTab(self.mode_1_tabs_widget), "Tab 4")
```

Now, when `SampleTab` gets created, it has a parent.
Do the same for your `mode_2_tabs_widget`

**EDIT**

Please note that, you have to pass `self.mode_2_tabs_widget` as parent of `SampleTab` in the second case.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, I should have figured that out.  Thank you!